# Saving Outlook attachments with Python

Tags: python, parsing, outlook

I'm trying to save attachments (the files are NRG raw data files) from outlook emails to my desktop, but am receiving the following error: "AttributeError: <unknown>.SaveAsFile"

Everything works fine (I think) until I try to save the file...

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")



inbox = outlook.Folders["myinboxfolder"].Folders["Inbox"].Folders["[folder i need]"]
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
attachment = message.attachments

attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\Users\my name \Desktop\Unsorted' + attachment.FileName)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + attachment.FileName)
```

This should copy the file to your current working directory. Then you could use the shutil module to copy the file to the destination you desire:

```
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

or you can move the file instead of copying using:

```
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Here are the shutil docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but:

shouldn't the file location be using two \'s for each directory level, so:

```
attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\\Users\\my name \\Desktop\\Unsorted' + attachment.FileName)
```

Also shouldn't you have a `\\` or `\` after "Unsorted", or are you saving the file to your desktop and calling it `UnsortedYourFileAttachmentNameHere.xls` so the working line should be:

```
attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAMEHERE\\Desktop\\Unsorted\\' + attachment.FileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ".SaveAsFile" should be used on 'attachment.Item'

```
inbox = outlook.Folders["myinboxfolder"].Folders["Inbox"].Folders["[folder i need]"]
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
attachment = message.attachments
attachment_item = attachment.Item

attachment_item.SaveAsFile('C:\Users\my name \Desktop\Unsorted' + attachment_item.FileName)
```

or, you can loop through Attachments

```
inbox = outlook.Folders["myinboxfolder"].Folders["Inbox"].Folders["[folder i need]"]
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
attachment = message.attachments

for i in attachment:
    i.SaveAsFile('C:\Users\my name \Desktop\Unsorted' + i.FileName)
```